# Size of a BQ Table from GCS

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

Is there a way to calculate the final size of a BigQuery table based on the size of the Cloud Storage data?

For example, an 80GB bucket, it's transformed into a 100GB table.

I want an approximation to know if a Cloud Storage bucket could be less than 100GB in BQ.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is hard.  It will vary as a function of how the data in the files in GCS are stored.  If you have 80GB of data and that data is in CSV the BQ size will be one value but if it is stored in JSON then it will be another value and if its AVRO yet another and so on.  It will also be a function of the schema types for your columns and how many columns you have.  Google has documented how much storage (in BQ) is required for each of the data types:

In the docs on [BQ Storage Pricing](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#storage) there is a table showing the amount of data required to store different column types.

If I needed to know the resulting BQ size from a file of data, I would determine each of my resulting columns, the data size for each column (average) and that would give me the approximate size of a row in the BQ table.  From there, I would multiply that by the number of rows in my source files.

Another way you might want to try is to load in some existing files one at a time and see what the "apparent" multiplier is.  In theory, that might be a good enough indication for given sets of file / table pairs.